# Is there a way to retain an Add-On's preferences when updating the Add-on?

Tags: python, customization

I have a couple of preference properties (string, boolean, float) in my add-on and they all have a default value in their defining statement.

When I install an update to my add-on, the previously modified settings are not saved and the default values are used instead.

Is there a way to save the settings before the update and restore them afterwards?
Or do I have to get rid of the default values from the properties? (That would be not so good.)

I was looking at the application handlers but I could not find a handler for add-on updates.

Does anyone have a best practice method for dealing with add-on preferences? Thanks in advance.

Update: here is how my add-on settings are defined:

```
class PREF_PT_Preferences(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __package__

    pref_library_path: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="pref_library_path",subtype="DIR_PATH", description = '...', default=Library_Location)
    pref_local_lib_path: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="pref_local_lib_path",subtype="DIR_PATH",description = '...', default="")
    pref_stage_height: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name ='pref_stage_height', description = '...', default=(240), soft_min=0, soft_max=1000)
```

Comment: Really important question. I would like to know the answer as well. Maybe you could let the readers know, how you are updating the addon?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention that: I let the users install the add on, explicitly asking them not to remove the older version before the installation. The add on has the same name and installs over the old version. The update works fine, just the user modified preference settings are lost after the update.

Comment: I have an idea for a ridiculous hack. In the register portion of your addon, check for a custom attribute, that persists (like on the window_manager). If it doesn't exist create it and make it store the addon preferences. If it exists, copy those values to the addon preferences.

Comment: Interesting idea. Thanks. I still hope that there is an "official" way of dealing with this. To be honest, I was lacking the time to check other add-ons from professional programmers how they do it. It's not so easy to follow others code (I am a beginner developer) and it would be less "painful" if someone who knows this well, would explain it properly.

Comment: So, I check my addons and this is the default behaviour. The settings are not overriden. Are you defining your preferences in a class, that inherits from ```bpy.types.AddonPreferences``` with ```:```-properties?

Comment: I updated my original post with the definition code.

Comment: There is no official way: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/71486